# Does Go support type casting/conversion for functions?

Tags: function, go, type-conversion

I am writing a library named ["GoRequest"](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest) which wraps around net/http package and is meant for making an easy http client.

Now, I am having a problem with function conversion which has similar types as its parameters. Here is my problem snippet.

```
type Request *http.Request
type Response *http.Response

func (s *SuperAgent) RedirectPolicy(policy func(req Request, via []Request) error) *SuperAgent {
   s.Client.CheckRedirect = policy
   return s
}
```

s.Client.CheckRedirect is a member in [http.Client struct](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) and should receive `func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error`

As you might see, I want to convert `func(req Request, via []Request) error` --> `func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request)` which has similar types of parameters.

But it returns me an error:

```
./main.go:142: cannot use policy (type func(Request, []Request) error) as type func(*http.Request, []*http.Request) error in assignment
```

I cannot find any document for this kind of conversion and if it's possible, please suggest.
If not, please suggest some other good way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: there is no type-aliasing in Go, every declared type is a new different type and hence the signature of both functions is technically very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just wrap `policy` in an anonymous function that would do the conversion for you? Something like this:

```
func (s *SuperAgent) RedirectPolicy(policy func(req Request, via []Request) error) *SuperAgent {
   s.Client.CheckRedirect = func(r *http.Request, v []*http.Request) error {
       return policy(Request(r), []Request(v))
   }
   return s
}
```

I'm not actually sure you can convert the `[]*http.Request` slice to a `[]Request`, but if not, you could create a temporary slice and do the interface conversion one by one:

```
func (s *SuperAgent) RedirectPolicy(policy func(req Request, via []Request) error) *SuperAgent {
   s.Client.CheckRedirect = func(r *http.Request, v []*http.Request) error {
       vv := make([]Request, len(v))
       for i, r := range v {
           vv[i] = Request(r)
       }
       return policy(Request(r), vv)
   }
   return s
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks! The second example is great. It needs a loop for type casting on array.